# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.camera = _ref')

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo-camera

-App dev in React Native-
Hello,
I have a problem with Expo Camera. Here an error is referred when you want to take a picture.

"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.camera = _ref')" / Scan.js.

If the app is freshly updated with Expo, everything works. But as soon as you continue programming and another error occurs, this error appears and doesn't go away until you refresh the app again.

I have tried a lot, but I need help here.

Scan.js

````
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import {launchCamera, launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
import {Camera, Constants} from 'expo-camera';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import * as Haptics from 'expo-haptics';


import Images from '../assets/icon/index'



const Scan = () => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [status, requestPermission] = MediaLibrary.usePermissions();
  


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View/>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  
  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();

      Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Medium);

      console.log(photo.uri);
      MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri);
    }
  };

  
  
  
  

  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.camera}
        type={type}
        ref={ref => {
          this.camera = ref;
        }}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}
            >
            <Image source={Images.camera} style={styles.icon}></Image>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={takePicture}
          >
            <Text style={styles.text}>Take</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: 20,
    top: 0,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0.1,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
  },
  icon : {
    tintColor: 'white',
  },
})

export default Scan; ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new camera reference and attach it to the `Camera` component.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
...
const cameraRef = useRef<Camera>(null);
...
<Camera ref={cameraRef} ... />
```

In your `takePicture` function replace `this.camera.takePictureAsync` with `cameraRef.current?.takePictureAsync`

Comment: It worked for me, thank you very much. However, now comes a new message, with which I can not do anything. `Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-string-ref`.

Comment: Are you using another `ref`? If that's the case, create another reference using the `useRef` hook similar to the `cameraRef`

Comment: not that I know of

Answer (score 0):

Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-string-ref.

This is because the guy who answered used TypeScript.

Simply replace

const cameraRef = useRef(null);

with

const cameraRef = useRef(null);

Comment: It looks like the suggested replacement here is identical to what it's replacing.